# The icon disappears when you change the color of the button?

Tags: html, css

**NSFW warning about the link**

I have site:

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/lenjerie-sexy/rochii-sexy/rochie-amina.html)

On this page you will find your `add to cart button` is orange

Button has an icon `(a shopping cart)` ... the Track icon appears only if you delete the following code.

Please delete the code below and you'll see the icon appears.

```
.button.button span{
background:red !important;}
```

How can I make these icons appear even if the button is orange?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your HTML and CSS for the button. Also, if this link is NSFW please specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `background-color` instead of `background` since the font-icon is generated through background property.

Remove

```
.button.button span {
   background: red !important;
}
```

And add it instead here in this css property:

```
.product-view .add-to-cart button.button span span {
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 0 20px 0 70px;
  background: url('../images/icon_cart_product.png') 17px 50% no-repeat;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```